# LYX: How to remove white spaces between two figures

Tags: spacing, floats, lyx

Lyx is leaving a lot of white space between figures. I want to reduce this white space. How can I do this in LYX, I am not familiar with latex coding. Attached is the image of the actual page. 
In lyx documents I have figure floats as
float:Figure
float:Figure
float:Figure
[image]

Comment: Do you have a two-column document? Perhaps a special document class?

Comment: yes its a two-column document. This is the first time I am using lyx, i have been through tutorials to understand the basics but don't know how to get these small formatting right. I tried adding a vertical space between these figures and then giving it a very small custom value but the gap didn't reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\setlength\floatsep{1.25\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\textfloatsep{1.25\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\intextsep{1.25\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 2 pt}
```

Put the above in the preamble, and change the 1.25 to desired one.

The First Line is for length between two adjacent floats

The Second Line -  for floats on top and bottom of text only
For floats at top - length between float and text below it
For floats at bottom - length between float and text above it

The Third Line- for floats in the middle of text only - length between text above it, and text below it.